# TYPO3 Fluid Templates variables

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm trying to set a variable in a Fluid template.
I try to divide something by 2 :

`<f:variable name="hmc">{menu->f:count()} / 2</f:variable>`

It does not work because I get a string instead of a numeric result.

Comment: are you sure you need to calculate? most situations also can be handled with the `iterator` variable from the `f:for` VH. see [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/10.4/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/For.html#iteration), and [example](https://fluidtypo3.org/library/code-examples.html?tx_fluidshare_display%5Baction%5D=display&tx_fluidshare_display%5Bcontroller%5D=Gist&tx_fluidshare_display%5Bgist%5D=31&cHash=3d213cc7a60fc3b4891a41ed9cfc83e3)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it in a one-liner. You have to count first and then do the math.

```
<f:variable name="count">{menu -> f:count()}</f:variable>
<f:variable name="hmc">{count / 2}</f:variable>
```